# Toggling Display On Large Div

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a div with a ton of markup in it and a button that I'm using to toggle the display of that div.

The toggling of that div is slow and buggy - especially on an iPad. Why is this? Is there a way I can speed it up?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript with jQuery?

Comment: Yup. And I'm not even using any effects like slideDown or fadeIn because those perform even worse.

Comment: See my answer. Maybe jQuery does some logic beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

You could move it off screen:

```
#div.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
}
```

But is it really that slow? You could try it with vanilla JS, if that works:

```
document.getElementById('div').style.display = 'none';
```